# @ doesn't suppress errors in php

Tags: php, error-handling

I have several errors in my php error log on code that should be suppressing errors with the @ operator. For example:

```
@unlink($path.'_expire');
```

trows an error in the error log that there is no file or directory named "_expire".

This code is in a third party library and I don't want to modify it, I just need php to suppress the error as I think was intended.

My error reporting is set to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Error suppressing is making the errors not break the code. But E_ALL is reporting on all the ERRORS in the log file. If you want to get rid of the log file errors use error_reporting = 0

Comment: Although it is best to fix it. <?php 
             if (file_exists($path.'_expire'){
                 unlink($path.'_expire');
             }
         ?>

Comment: I see, so there's no way to suppress the error without disabling error reporting? I'll have to modify the 3rd party code?

Comment: `@` _should_ normally suppress these, unless (1) you enabled something like xdebug's scream or (2) you have a custom error handler, which does _not_ check what the `error_reporting()` return in that function is (it will _always_ be called, but error_reporting() will in that callback temporarily be `0`).

Comment: @ContextSwitch: if by "modify" you mean "fix", then yes.

Comment: I would just modify the code... Have it check the file_exists... three lines and your headache is over. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was using a separate error handler. I added the following check to my error handler:

```
if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
    // This error code is not included in error_reporting
    return;
}
```

and now it correctly skips suppressed errors.

source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php